# Download a file through http-auth

Tags: java, android, http, download, http-authentication

I can't download file with basic http-auth. I have auth string for authorization, but i get exception: FileNotFound.
Code:

```
URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                URLConnection  conection =  url.openConnection();

                conection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authString);
                conection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                conection.setDoInput(true);
                conection.setDoOutput(true);
                conection.connect();



                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();


                // Exception on line below
                BufferedInputStream  input = new BufferedInputStream(conection.getInputStream()); 

                // Output stream
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
...
```

lenghtOfFile isn't 0. Besides, I tried using HtppClient for this task, but get exception too.

Comment: Remove setDoOutput(true) line.

Comment: Thanks, it's help me )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have commented, you should remove the line setDoOutput(true) because this is GET request.